# .htaccess url to post by slug

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I have blog with posts. When i click on read more button i want to redirect and show selected post. Wanted url is http://www.solutions.com/blog/blog-post/slug.

**In .htaccess i have this:**

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^solutions\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.solutions.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
!-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 
$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^blog/blog-post/(.+)
blog/blog-post.php?slug=$1
```

**But I get an error:**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

How can I solve this?

Comment: there was a nice .htaccess tester, check it here https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

Would the PLUS sign in the last line be causing the problem?

So instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/blog-post/(.+) blog/blog-post.php?slug=$1
```

try

```
RewriteRule ^blog/blog-post/(.*) blog/blog-post.php?slug=$1
```